# python - file was loaded in the wrong encoding utf-8

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, pycharm

im quite new to programing and i don´t understand this error message i get, `file was loaded in the wrong encoding utf-8` or it´s not really a error message in the code but i get it in my new .txt file where i write all found keywords to. The .txt file get upp to 4000+ rows with information that i sort to Excel in another program and later send it to Access. What dose the message mean and is thhere a way to fix it? Thanks

im using pycharm with anaconda36

[image]

```
import glob


def LogFile(filename, tester):

    data = []
    with open(filename) as filesearch:   # open search file
        filesearch = filesearch.readlines()   # read file
    file = filename[37:]
    for line in filesearch:
        if tester in line:   # extract "Create Time"
            short = line[30:]
            data.append(short)   # store all found wors in array

    print (file)

    with open('Msg.txt', 'a') as handler:  # create .txt file

        for i in range(len(data)):
            handler.write(f"{file}|{data[i]}")


# open with 'w' to "reset" the file.
with open('LogFile.txt', 'w') as file_handler:
    pass
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

for filename in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\Documents\Access\\GTX797\*.log'):
    LogFile(filename, 'Sending Request: Tester')
```

Comment: what IDE are you using?

Comment: If you're going to ask a question about a message you see in your text editor, tell us which text editor you're using.

Comment: @AzatIbrakov im using pycharm with anaconda

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error in pyCharm and fixed it by specifying UTF-8 when creating the file. You will need to import codecs to do this.

```
import codecs

with codecs.open(‘name.txt', 'a', 'utf-8-sig') as f:
```